# CreateFile() fails and GetLastError() returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED while writing to file in Temp directory

Tags: windows, winapi, access-denied, createfile

I am using Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I have code to dump memory buffer to file. Here it is:

```
//
// DumpMemoryToFileW()
//  дампим память в файл (Unicode-версия)
// lpFileName - имя файла
// lpData     - блок памяти
// dataSize   - размер блока
//
BOOL DumpMemoryToFileW( LPWSTR lpFileName, LPVOID lpData, SIZE_T dataSize )
{
    HANDLE  hFile       = NULL;
    DWORD   dwWritten   = 0;

    // откроем файл
    hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // отладочное сообщение
        DebugPrint(DEBUG_ERROR, "Could not open file; lpFileName = %ws\n", lpFileName);

        // выходим с ошибкой
        return FALSE;
    }

    // запишем код
    if(!WriteFile(hFile, lpData, (DWORD)dataSize, &dwWritten, NULL))
    {
        // отладочное сообщение
        DebugPrint(DEBUG_ERROR, "Could not write to file; hFile = 0x%p; lpFileName = %ws\n", hFile, lpFileName);

        // закрываем хэндл
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        // выходим с ошибкой
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I need to save some data to temporary file; so I use `GetTempPath()` and `GetTempFileName()` to create file name, and then call `DumpMemoryToFileW()`:

```
// получим временную директорию
GetTempPathW(sizeof(wTempPath) / sizeof(WCHAR), wTempPath);

// сгенерируем имя EXE-файла
GetTempFileNameW(wTempPath, L"", 0, wFilename);

// запишем имя файла
if(!DumpBlockToFileW(wFilename, lpData))
{
    // отладочное сообщение
    DebugPrint(DEBUG_ERROR, "Could not write to file; exiting with error.\n");

    // освободим память
    FREE_MEMORY_BLOCK(&Data);

    // выходим с ошибкой
    return FALSE;
}
```

`DumpBlockToFileW()` is a macro using my `MEMORY_BLOCK` structure (buffer and size); it expands to `DumpMemoryToFileW()`. But `DumpMemoryToFileW()` fails and error is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - so, it could not write to temp file! File was created (I can see it in directory with zero size), but `CreateFile()` fails.

What is the problem?

**UPDATE:** That is debug output:

```
[484] [INFO] <script.cpp:723 PID:484 TID:1988 ERR:6> SaveAndUpdate(): File downloaded; Data.Length = 73728
[484] [INFO] <script.cpp:736 PID:484 TID:1988 ERR:0> SaveAndUpdate(): Temp file name for writing: C:\Users\TESTW7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\9E53.tmp
[484] [ERROR] <memory.cpp:123 PID:484 TID:1988 ERR:5> DumpMemoryToFileW(): Could not open file; lpFileName = C:\Users\TESTW7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\9E53.tmp
[484] [ERROR] <script.cpp:742 PID:484 TID:1988 ERR:5> SaveAndUpdate(): Could not write to file; exiting with error.
```

And this is the code of `DebugPrint()`:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DebugPrint(info, x, ...) ExtendedDebugPrint((info), (x), __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugPrint
#endif // _DEBUG

EXTERNC VOID __cdecl ExtendedDebugPrint( DWORD dwInfoLevel, LPSTR lpszFormat, LPSTR lpszFile, DWORD dwLine, LPSTR lpszFunc, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    CHAR    szString[4200]  = { 0 };
    LPSTR   lpszInfoLevel   = NULL;

    // получим аргументы
    va_start(args, lpszFunc);

    // получим имя самого файла
    if(strrchr(lpszFile, '\\'))
        lpszFile = strrchr(lpszFile, '\\') + 1;

    // отформатируем строку
    wsprintf(szString, "[%s] <%s:%d PID:%d TID:%d ERR:%d> %s(): ", 
        infoLevels[dwInfoLevel], lpszFile, dwLine, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), GetLastError(), lpszFunc);

    // напечатаем в строку
    wvsprintf(&(szString[strlen(szString)]), lpszFormat, args);

    // выведем в дебаг
    OutputDebugString(szString);

    // закончим работу с аргументами
    va_end(args);
}
```

**UPDATE2:** It is Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: the code you post works fine. Can you tell from which point you have `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` ? I think it not relative to `DumpMemoryToFileW()`. What is `lpData` in your case ?

Comment: `lpData` is a pointer to `MEMORY_BLOCK` structure which contains pointer to memory buffer and size of the buffer. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` is because `CreateFile()` fails.

Comment: You don't call `GetLastError`. How can you know what it returns?

Comment: My `DebugPrint()` calls `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Why don't you make an MCVE so that you don't have to describe the code to us and so we can trust that we know what you code really is. You could also usefully show us the output of your debugging. For instance, it would be useful to know what the filename is.

Comment: Added debug output and code to question.

Comment: Your call to GetLastError must be immediately after the failed API call. It's not. At least, you cannot guarantee it. Please call GetLastError immediately after CreateFile returns. Why won't you make an MCVE?

Comment: I followed it in debugger. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` appears after call to `CreateFileW()`.

Comment: Try disabling your virus checker if you have one.

Comment: It is Trusteer Rapport, I have disabled it and it works fine! Thank you.

Comment: @deselect: Makes one wonder why Trusteer Rapport is blocking temp files in the temp directory. Unless Trusteer Rapport is actively scanning the file while you are trying to open it (you are calling `GetTempFileName()` in a manner that lets it create the file for you before you then open it). You should always have write access to your own temp folder, so you might consider detecting `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and re-attempt to open the file after a short timeout.

Comment: Also, for future reference, you can use SysInternals' [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tools to see who is accessing your files.

Comment: I use Process Explorer, but I didn't see any attempts to access this file. Maybe this is the kernel hook of `ZwCreateFile()`.

Comment: AV tools often cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: You are calling GetLastError at the wrong place. But never mind, you don't seem to care.

Comment: But it always works correctly and shows correct error code.